# LPA managing application

Tags: android, apk, euiccmanager

**
I'm currently trying to develop an android application to manage eSIM profiles including functions to download, enable, disable, delete profile. However at the current stage, I'm unable to even hit the LPA code while attempting to download the profile from a hardcoded LPA string within the code.

My download profile code for reference:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
euiccManager.downloadSubscription(
downloadableSubscription,
true,
callbackIntent
)
```

//where downloadableSubscription:

```
private lateinit var downloadableSubscription: DownloadableSubscription
```

//from.....import android.telephony.euicc.DownloadableSubscription

```
downloadableSubscription = DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode("String_value_of_the_activation_code")
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------**
I'm sure the function is being executed since I've defined 2 toast prints before and after the function and they are showing up fine on the device.

API:33
Phone: Google Pixel 4
APK is a signed release using self-signed certificate (this self signed certificate's hashvalue is also being configured on the metadata of the Profile I'm trying to download, so I'm wondering this shouldn't be a problem during the signature match check)
Also for some context I work in a company that deals in such subscription service management, and I'm testing the possibility of developing an inhouse app to work-around the profiles.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.